# Flutter change bool (with setState) in other dart file

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a splash screen with stacks. When everything is done loading, i want to change the bool splashScreenIsLoading to false.

This is my code in my main.dart

```
bool splashScreenIsLoading = true;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          loginScreen(),
          showRightSplash(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class showRightSplash extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _showRightSplashState createState() => _showRightSplashState();
}

class _showRightSplashState extends State<showRightSplash> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return splashScreenIsLoading == true ? splashScreen() : splashScreen2();
  }
}

splashScreen() {
  return Text(
    "SHOW SPLASH SCREEN",
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50, color: Colors.red),
  );
}

splashScreen2() {
  return Text(
    "HIDE SPLASH SCREEN",
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50, color: Colors.red),
  );
}
```

In my file (a different .dart file) loginScreen(), I have this in initState

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);
    doTasks()
    setState(() {
      splashScreenIsLoading = false;
    });
  }
```

It doesn't work, only when I hot reload when everything is loaded. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Is doTasks() asynchronous or synchronous?

Comment: doTask() is an async function

Answer (score 0):

Since your `doTasks()` is asynchronous function, edit your initState like this:

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);
    doTasks().then((_){
      setState(() {
        splashScreenIsLoading = false;
      });
    });
  }
```

Also you can simplify your code like this:

```
splashScreenIsLoading ? splashScreen() : splashScreen2()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried the code but it stays the same, it only changes when I hot reload...

Comment: It should work, do you have any problem with `Stack` widget, it seems unusual. always make `MaterialApp` parent of `Scaffold` instead Stack. Also can you @KarelDebedts share errors?

Comment: I don't get any errors, I think the problem is that I set State from another dart file...

Comment: @KarelDebedts I see, you have different problem, solution of the code you shared is my answer, no doubt about this.